# How to TTY on Debian into Huawei e5573s

Tags: tty, ttyusb

i want to establish serial connection com port to Huawei e5573s connected via USB, so i can send some AT commands at it

as far as i understand, i need to establish a TTY connection to the device on com port to do the above.

i tried usb_modeswitch -J -v 12d1 -p 14db but the switch fails with:

```
Error: can't use storage command in MessageContent with interface 0;
interface class is 2, expected 8. Abort
```

i just dont know how to connect to it. on windows it is suggested to use putty, and some custom drivers.
what tools do i need to use on Debian to achieve the description above?

// edit 1

```
lsusb | grep Huawei
<< Bus 001 Device 004: ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.

for file in $(find /sys/dev/ -name 189:3);
do
source ${file}/uevent; echo $DEVNAME;
done;

<< bus/usb/001/004
```

so then, my modem mount point is:

```
/dev/bus/usb/001/004

screen /dev/bus/usb/001/004
   << '/dev/bus/usb/001/004' is not a tty
```

which means i have to enable serial on the device, using usb_modeswitch.

// edit 2

the device was in the correct mode from the start (i thought i was putting it into tty mode, but instead, put it in the storage mode by creating .rules file for usb_modeswitch)

For some reason it is not showing as ttyUSB, and i cannot find what it attaches to

```
cdc_ether 1-2:1.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-2,
CDC Ethernet Device, 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
```

Comment: `cdc_ether` is a network interface. It shows `eth0`, however it mey be renamed to something like `enx0123456789ab` where the part after the `enx` is the MAC address. You can use dhcp to get an address (or just use a static address such as 192.168.8.10/24) and then use a browser to talk to 192.168.8.1. I don't know if this model supports a serial interface.